# How do you delete 1st 7 lines of several *.txt files in a folder using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder with nearly 150 *.txt files. I need to delete the 1st seven lines of every .txt file in that folder using python3.5.2

Comment: Python seems to be a wrong tool for the task

Comment: @JackMoody I have many files, not one file

Comment: @slash Use a loop.

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? You need to loop through each file and then do what is mentioned in the link I’ve given.

Comment: All the files are structured like this:

Name:
Source:
RPS:
LIMP:
CULP:
MCL:
DVS:
34
345
2321
232
4564
3245
9098

I want to delete lines from 0 to 6. i am trying to use os.walk. here is my code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's [OS Module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to get the names of all *.txt files from your folder. Then you can iterate over this names, read all lines from each file and overwrite the file with the lines you want to keep:

```
from os import listdir, path

path_str = '.'  # your directory path
txts = [f for f in listdir(path_str)
        if f.endswith('.txt') and path.isfile(path.join(path_str, f))]

for txt in txts:
    with open(txt, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    with open(txt, 'w') as f:
        f.write(''.join(lines[7:]))
```

Comment: that worked. thanks :)